# similar function of getprocaddress to use a struct?

Tags: c++, dll, struct, code-injection, getprocaddress

I have a DLL from a game I'm importing into a windows32 application, I've successfully loaded it and have called quite a few functions. However I'm facing a problem with a certain function I need to use needs a structure passed to it.

It seems when I disassemble the DLL I can see the structures and the data types in the structure, however how would I use this structure?

AFAIK GetProcAddress wouldnt work?

I'm looking for a way to use this struct.

```
    *(_DWORD *)this = tagRX_GLOBAL___vftable_;
    RX__g_pGlobal = (struct tagRX_GLOBAL *)this;
```

Comment: It is not a struct, it is a C++ class.  The vftable variable points to the v-table, a list of pointers to virtual methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add a simple function that will return you an address of the struct.
Functions are fine with `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: thanks, but how would you go about modifying the members in the struct? could i possibly get an example of how to get the reference to the struct and access the members?

Comment: You need to pick up the layout of the struct from some header to access the members. Dll itself simply does not contain this info. This is not a .net dll.

Comment: i have the variable layout, however is there a resource i could look at to see implementation of the struct and getting a reference to it?